# How do players defeat the coin dragon in Gorgoldand's Gauntlet?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, published-adventures, encounter-design

There is a one-shot adventure called [Gorgoldand's Gauntlet](http://www.anxaludens.org/imperium/download/gauntlet.pdf), originally designed to be run with 3.5 rules.

The adventure mostly consists of a series of puzzles, traps, and a few encounters. However, the climax of the adventure has the players fighting a "Coin Dragon". After reading through the adventure, it does not seem to indicate a way that a group of characters can kill the dragon.

> Most ordinary weapons do little or no damage to the coin
>   dragon. Piercing and slashing weapons slide right through the
>   loose objects in its “body,” doing no damage. A blunt weapon
>   like a mace or club might dislodge a handful of coins, but these
>   are easily returned to the coin dragon the following round.
>   (They are sucked back into the creature’s body telekinetically.)
>   A dispel magic cast upon the creature causes the disparate
>   objects forming the dragon’s body to crash to the floor, leaving
>   the dragon “bodiless.” The creature reforms its “body” the
>   following round, but this allows PCs time to escape (possibly
>   with an item or two from the hoard). The coin dragon is not
>   permanently destroyed until it loses all of its hit points.
>   The coin dragon never leaves its treasure room and naturally
>   heals 3 hit points per day. PCs in combat with a coin
>   dragon might find it necessary to do some damage, leave the
>   treasure room to heal up and prepare new spells, then continue
>   the assault later (possibly over the course of several
>   days, depending on the strength of the party).
>
> SQ—Construct: Immune to mind-influencing effects, poison,
>   disease, and similar effects. Not subject to critical hits, subdual
>   damage, ability damage, energy drain, or death from massive
>   damage.
>
> SQ—Resistances (Ex): The coin dragon has acid, cold, electricity,
>   and fire resistance 5.

If I'm reading this correctly, it seems like any weapon attack with non-magical weapons are easily shrugged off. It looks like it's possible to deal magical damage to the monster, but it appears to be immune or resistant to most kinds of damage.

This is an encounter designed for a group of 1st level players. Given that spell casting is limited at 1st level, or that a party might not consist of an offensive spell caster, how is it possible to defeat this foe? Specifically, as the campaign was written, how was the foe intended to be defeated, or is it not intended to be defeated?

Comment: The notation used on the dragon's DR suggests that the adventure is a 3e, rather than 3.5e adventure. If  so, the DM is supposed to do some conversion, and IIRC, the DR 10/+1 might be reduced to DR 5/Magic, conventionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Damage it a bit and run away to come back later

It only heals 3 hit points per day so if you can use your spells to do more than that much on average day (which shouldn't be hard even at level 1), you can kill it over time. This is specifically called out in the description:

> The coin dragon never leaves its treasure room and naturally heals 3 hit points per day. PCs in combat with a coin dragon might find it necessary to do some damage, leave the treasure room to heal up and prepare new spells, then continue the assault later

You probably need Magic Missle since its the only damaging level 1 spell that the dragon doesnt resist. Otherwise, this will be very difficult as the only way level 1 characters can damage him effectively is through perfect rolls on Shocking Grasp or Chill Touch (which can deal 6 damage on a maximum roll beating the 5 resist)

Comment: Ok; but how does a character damage it? If all weapon damage does neglectable damage, and all 1st level spells are resisted with the exception of magic missile (which only does 2-5 damage), then the only option players have to defeat it is to have at-least one wizard or sorcerer in the group that knows magic missile and uses all their spells to cast that single spell... If any of those conditions are not met, this monster becomes impossible to kill, correct?

Comment: @onewho you can deal damage through resistance. It only reduces damage

Comment: 3.5 offensive spells 
Cantrips:
No offensive cantrip does more than 3 damage, all are resisted.
1st level: 
Burning Hands 2-5 damage (5 fire resistance-no net damage)
Shocking grasp 1-6 damage (5 electric resistance - 1 net damage possible)
Chill touch 1-6 damage (5 cold resistance - 1 net damage possible)
Ray of enfeeblement 1d6 str damage (immunity to energy drain no effect)
The only spell that can damage effectively through it's resistances is magic missile.

Comment: @onewho I guess you need magic missle then (or to have a bunch of sorcerer or wizards that have grasp or chill touch and a lot of luck)

Comment: There is a time-honoured technique in D&D for dealing with monsters that are not vulnerable to normal weapons, which is to hit them with magical ones. Your first level PC's don't have magical weapons? Then they can use the ones provided.

Comment: @Richardb if you have an answer to the question, leave it as an answer not in the comments

Comment: Also sonic damage. People always forget about sonic. So do designers. Usually lower damage, but 1d4 every time is better than 1 damage, a sixth of the time.

Comment: People also forget about psionic damage. Plus psionics have a few powers at 1st which would work.

Comment: @nijineko “Psionic” isn’t a damage type; psionic powers deal damage the same as spells do, using mostly the same types. The various *energy* powers use cold, fire, electricity, or sonic, for instance. The *mind thrust* power simply deals untyped damage, but not “psionic” damage.

Comment: @KRyan What no magic type of damage *cough*spellfire*cough*? I might be able to find a psionic type of damage if I look hard enough, or I could just be miss-remembering and thinking of magic damage type. Maybe that was a 3.0 thing somewhere. I'm not motivated enough to search and find whatever it was I read  right now.

Comment: @nijineko In D&D \$3.x\text{e}\$, *spellfire* deals the same sort of damage as *flame strike*, that is, half fire damage, half untyped damage “directly from divine power.” Neither is magic damage.

Comment: Magic of Faerun calls it out as "half raw magical damage", which might update campaign book. Of course, I didn't finish reading the entire entry on spell fire, so maybe the text calls it out again later.

Answer (score 13):

Note: I've only read the dragon's entry in the linked PDF, not the whole adventure.

As [David Coffron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130423/20971) said, kill it incrementally. The dragon heals 3hp/day, has DR 10/+1, and resist all relevant elements (that is, all elements that can be used to cause magical damage in the core book with 0th and 1st level spells) 5 and 18 hp.

As mentioned, [Magic Missile](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicMissile.htm) will do straight damage to the dragon.

Let's posit, though, that there's a [Barbarian](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/barbarian.htm) in the party who rolled well, so has an 18 STR and is using a two-handed Greatsword (2d6 damage). That's 2d6+6 damage, for an average of 13 per round (1d6 averages 3.5, 2d6 averages 7, + 1.5x STR). The barbarian can Rage for a few rounds, adding +4 to STR, so +3 to damage (thus, averaging 16 damage per round). At this point, the barbarian is, on average dealing enough damage per attack to negate two day's worth of "fast healing".

But, wait: there's more!

Someone can cast [Magic Weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicWeapon.htm) on our barbarian's sword, thus adding another point of damage (average 17). At this point, the barbarian's average damage is 17 (minimum of 11), *and* is bypassing the dragon's DR (since the sword now has a +1 enhancement bonus, and thus bypasses DR/magic).

> Some monsters are vulnerable to magic weapons. Any weapon with at least a +1 magical enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls overcomes the damage reduction of these monsters.

-- [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction)

Two hits from the barbarian, and the dragon is no more. And one hit wouldn't be shocking.

Meanwhile, the druid can cast [Shillelagh](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shillelagh.htm), and their quarterstaff is now a +1 weapon dealing 1d10 damage; even with a +0 STR, that's an average of 6.5 damage per round; if they're hesitant to enter melee, they can also pair up with the cleric to cast [Magic Stone](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicStone.htm), and start throwing rocks for 1d6+1 damage (again, bypassing the dragon's DR); it's only 3 rocks each at an average of 4.5 damage per rock, but it's still 13.5 damage per character.

[Magic Stone](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicStone.htm) lasts 30 minutes, [Shillelagh](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shillelagh.htm) and [Magic Weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicWeapon.htm) both last a minute per level, and raging is a free action which lasts for 3+CON rounds at a time (including the CON bonus you get for raging, so it's almost guaranteed to be more than 5 rounds).

So, the cleric casts Magic Stone and prepares to throw rocks or provide healing. The druid and the wizard cast Shillelagh and Magic Weapon (respectively) as the barbarian prepares to rage and charge the dragon while the cleric opens the door. The PCs win initiative, so the barbarian rages and charges, taking the dragon down to 4 HP. The cleric throws a stone and misses, the wizard casts Magic Missile and rolls minimum, bringing the dragon to 2 hp, and the druid charges in with her quarterstaff and finishes it off.

With a full spell list (and a little luck with the dice, of course), it's not hard to see the party finishing the dragon off before it gets to act.

Comment: And in the worst case, if the PCs fear for their lives, they can just retreat and come back the next day. A monster who does not pursue is the equivalent of a sitting duck.

Comment: @annoyingimp: do'h, and that's why I picked a great sword, too. Good catch!

Answer (score 9):

There is a time-honoured technique in D&D for dealing with monsters that are not vulnerable to normal weapons, which is to hit them with magical ones. A +1 weapon is sufficient to overcome the damage resistance, and there are several thoughtfully provided in area 13.

If your party isn't powerful enough to take it out in one combat you can back enough, heal up, pick your most suitable spells and go for another round.

Comment: Good catch, I missed those. It's unfortunate that they aren't optimal weapons though. The +1 falchion is the most likely to make a difference. The spiked gauntlet will restrict one combatant to fist only combat, and the 2 siangham are exotic weapons, so it's unlikely a first level party will have someone who can wield them.

Comment: @onewho: You are forgetting the [Magic Weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicWeapon.htm) spell, available to Clr 1, Pal 1, Sor/Wiz 1, War 1 and lasting 1 minute per level (10 rounds at level 1). And if your party does not have any character of those classes; hopefully it has someone with some Charisma and a few points in Use Magic Device and can find a half-used wand...